# Anyone know of a calendar web widget for my website I could use?

Tags: html, css, feed

I hate the google calendar widget, mainly because you can't style it! So does anyone know of a calendar widget that can display my google calendar feed? I've had a good look around and I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 4):

I personally love FullCalendar by Adam Shaw:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

It even has support for google calendar events:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/google_calendar/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery and jQuery UI, you could take a look at [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).